# List variable changing to <class 'NoneType'> inside If statement and does not allow any list operations inside the If statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Hi I am trying to read precipitation files from a folder and calculate total precipitation for a year. Using os and pandas to loop through sub director and read files. Each file contains data for 1 year. Then calculating total precipitation for each year.

I am also trying to get a list of years where total precipitation is zero. So I declared an empty list (`zero_year = []`) then used if condition to append years where total precipitation is zero to the empty list.

**My problem is that the zero_year switches to class 'NoneType' inside the if statement and will not allow me to append the years with zero precipitation to zero_year list.**

I think I am missing something very basic.
Appreciate any help I can get.

```
# Walk through all subfolders and files under the "Precipitation" directory
# 1st loop gets list of sub directory under precipitation
# 2nd loop is for files under the sub directory
import os
import pandas as pd
filepath = "Precipitation\\"

global zero_year
for sub_directory in os.listdir(filepath):
    sub_filepath = filepath + sub_directory
   
    zero_year = []
    print(type(zero_year))

    for filename in os.listdir(sub_filepath):
        full_filepath = (sub_filepath + "\\" + filename)
        current_year = filename[6:8] + filename[9:]
                        
        # Read Precipitation File
        precip_file = pd.read_csv(full_filepath, sep=" ", header=None,
                                  skipinitialspace=True, names=["Day", "Precip (mm)"], index_col=False)
        
        # Remove the last row that has no data using drop
        precip_file.drop(precip_file.tail(1).index, inplace=True)

        # Convert all strings to no data ---- NaN
        precip_file = precip_file.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
        
        # Sum all precipitation value in file to get total precipitation value for a year
        yearly_total = precip_file["Precip (mm)"].sum(skipna=True)
          
        # List years where total precipitation is zero
        if yearly_total == 0:                     
            zero_year = zero_year.extend(current_year)
            print(type(zero_year))
            print(zero_year)
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.extend()` extends the list in-place, so it modifies the existing list then returns `None`, instead of creating a new list and returning that.

If you change

```py
zero_year = zero_year.extend(current_year)
```

to

```py
zero_year.extend(current_year)
```

it should work.

Comment: Ahh, I forgot about this. Thanks that did the trick.